# Consumir WebService

Tags: html, http, autenticação

Olá, tenho um link de um serviço http://exemplo.meuwebservice:(porta)/paraexemplo/ que ao acessar via navegador web, me pede login e senha e consigo result em json (apenas após inserir usuário e senha).

"campo":"dado" ;

Gostaria de ajuda para escrever uma página, talvez em javascript, para consumir este webservice. Estou com problemas para passar na autenticação http básica. 
Algum link e/ou sugestão do que procurar e/ou por onde começar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a='stringsearch';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$url = "http://exemplo.meuwebservice:(porta)/paraexemplo/$a";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Accept: application/json" );


$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);


curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($output);
$json_output = json_decode($output, true);
foreach($json_output as $item){
    foreach($item as $dados){
    echo $dados;
    }
}
```